# shell script parsing issue: unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?)

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

***What I am doing?***
I have one JSON file as sonar-report.json. I want to iterate sonar-report.json in shell script, to read values of json.
To parse JSON file I am using jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

So Following code I was trying to execute in shell script

```
alias jq=./jq-win64.exe
for key in $(jq '.issues | keys | .[]' sonar-report.json); do
    echo "$key"
    line=$(jq -r ".issues[$key].line" sonar-report.json)
done
```

***Problem***
When i execute this, console give me error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

If I update my above script, and add static index of array then script works fine

```
alias jq=./jq-win64.exe

for key in $(jq '.issues | keys | .[]' sonar-report.json); do
    echo "$key"
    line0=$(jq -r ".issues[0].line" sonar-report.json)
    line1=$(jq -r ".issues[1].line" sonar-report.json)
done
```

***so at the end what i want :***
I want to iterate values and print in console like

```
alias jq=./jq-win64.exe
for key in $(jq '.issues | keys | .[]' sonar-report.json); do
    line=$(jq -r ".issues[$key].line" sonar-report.json)
    echo $line
done
```

so the output should be

```
15
```

This is my JSON file as sonar-report.json

```
{
"issues": [
        {
            "key": "016B7970D27939AEBD",
            "component": "bits-and-bytes:src/main/java/com/catalystone/statusreview/handler/StatusReviewDecisionLedHandler.java",
            "line": 15,
            "startLine": 15,
            "startOffset": 12,
            "endLine": 15,
            "endOffset": 14,
            "message": "Use the \"equals\" method if value comparison was intended.",
            "severity": "MAJOR",
            "rule": "squid:S4973",
            "status": "OPEN",
            "isNew": true,
            "creationDate": "2019-06-21T15:19:18+0530"
        },
        {
            "key": "AWtqCc-jtovxS8PJjBiP",
            "component": "bits-and-bytes:src/test/java/com/catalystone/statusreview/service/StatusReviewInitiationSerivceTest.java",
            "message": "Fix failing unit tests on file \"src/test/java/com/catalystone/statusreview/service/StatusReviewInitiationSerivceTest.java\".",
            "severity": "MAJOR",
            "rule": "common-java:FailedUnitTests",
            "status": "OPEN",
            "isNew": false,
            "creationDate": "2019-06-18T15:32:08+0530"
        }
    ]
}
```

please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Works fine with Linux. Output is `15` and `Null`. You don't just want to use only `jq '.issues[].line'`?

Comment: I am using windows machine, so what should I do to fix this :(

Comment: Which version of jq are you using? And in what environment are you running it? (Cygwin? Msys2?)

Comment: I am using jq version 1.6 and i am running this under git bash, because I am writing a pre-commit hook to scan modified files in the repository

Comment: OK, I don't know much about Git on Windows (or anything on Windows) and I can't test any solution, but I suspect that you can just use the `-b` option as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks to me like an instance of Windows/Unix line-ending incompatibility, indicated in jq bugs [92 (for Cygwin)](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/92) and [1870 (for MSYS2)](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1870).

Any of the workarounds indicated in those bug reports should work, but once the fix gets into the release binary (presumably v1.7), the simplest solution is to use the new `-b` command-line option. (The option is available in recent jq preview builds; see the second bug report listed above):

```
for key in $(jq -b '.issues | keys | .[]' sonar-report.json); do
    line=$(jq -rb ".issues[$key].line" sonar-report.json)
    # I added quotes in the next line, because it's better style.
    echo "$line"
done
```

Until the next version of `jq` is available, or if you don't want to upgrade for some reason, a good workaround is to just remove the CRs by piping the output of `jq` through `tr -d '\r'`:

```
for key in $(jq -'.issues | keys | .[]' sonar-report.json | tr -d '\r'); do
    line=$(jq -r ".issues[$key].line" sonar-report.json | tr -d '\r')
    echo "$line"
done
```

However, as pointed out in a comment by Cyrus, you probably don't need to iterate line-by-line in a shell loop, which is incredibly inefficient since it leads to reparsing the entire JSON input many times. You can use jq itself to iterate, with the much simpler:

```
jq '.issues[].line' solar-response.json
```

which will parse the JSON file just once, and then produce each `.line` value in the file. (You probably still want to use the `-b` command-line option or other workaround, depending on what you intend to do with the output.)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't worked in windows git bash :( windows git bash giving me error  `Unknown option -b` and i am using JQ 1.6 latest version

Comment: @DupinderSingh: Ok, I guess the fix in bug report 1870 hasn't gone into the Windows binary yet. So use the `tr` workaround: `for key in $(jq '.issues | keys | .[]' sonar-report.json | tr -d '\r'); do

Comment: I know this is four years later, but for me "The term 'tr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."